# Crossing small array with a big array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of servers e.g.

```
servrs = ['A','B','C']
```

And then a list of co-ordinates (*route_csv*) that is around 100,000 obs long

For example

```
['query_id', 'from_lat', 'from_lon', 'to_lat', 'to_lon']
[1, 51.2, -0.5, 51.3, -0.6]
```

What I would like to do (for the purpose of multithreading) is split the list of co-ordinates into as many chunks as I have servers and then associate each chunk with a server. Order is not important

My way is horrible because I am looping through a numpy-array like so:

```
def CreateUrls(route_csv, servrs):
    out_urls = []
    i = 0
    while True:
        for x in servrs:
            out_urls.append(["%s/viaroute?loc=%.5f,%.5f&loc=%.5f,%.5f&alt=false&geometry=false" %
                            (x,
                             route_csv[i, ]['from_lat'],
                             route_csv[i, ]['from_lon'],
                             route_csv[i, ]['to_lat'],
                             route_csv[i, ]['to_lon']),
                             route_csv[i, ]['query_id']])
            i += 1
            if i == len(route_csv):
                return out_urls
```

Edit: To give a bit more context this then feeds into the script like so;

```
def RegOsrm(url_input):
    url_to_geocode, query_id = url_input
    try_c = 0
    while try_c < 3:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url_to_geocode)
            json_geocode = response.json()
            status = int(json_geocode['status'])
            # Found route between points
            if status == 200:
                tot_time_s = json_geocode['route_summary']['total_time']
                tot_dist_m = json_geocode['route_summary']['total_distance']
                used_from = json_geocode['via_points'][0]
                used_to = json_geocode['via_points'][1]
                out = [query_id,
                       status,
                       tot_time_s,
                       tot_dist_m,
                       used_from[0],
                       used_from[1],
                       used_to[0],
                       used_to[1]]
                print(out)
                return out
            # Cannot find route between points (code errors as 999)
            elif status == 207:
              return [query_id, 999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        except Exception:
            time.sleep(2)
            try_c += 1
    print("Failed: %d %s" % (query_id, url_to_geocode))
    return [query_id, 999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

url_routes = CreateUrls(route_csv=routes, servrs=servrs)
del routes, servrs
print("Created %d urls" % len(url_routes))

# Calculate routes using all threads
pool = Pool()
calc_routes = pool.map(RegOsrm, url_routes)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Can you include an example `route_csv`?

Comment: Thanks for including the example. Can you show how this is assigned to `route_csv` - do you mean for this to be a nested list?

Comment: Also, does your code work? I don't understand this access `route_csv[i, ]['from_lat']`.

Comment: Sorry lisa, it is a numpy array which has column names defined like so `return np.genfromtxt(csv_loc,
                             delimiter=',',
                             names=True,
                             usecols=("query_id", "from_lat", "from_lon", "to_lat", "to_lon"),
                             dtype=['<i8', '<f8', '<f8', '<f8', '<f8'])`

Comment: So does your code work at the moment?